# Why does user have to click twice to enable keyboard control for JQuery UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've implemented a custom slider here: http://jsfiddle.net/4wZ8d/

It works in a way that the slider handle is hidden initially, and when the user clicks anywhere on the slider the handle appears, by using:

```
$("a.ui-slider-handle").hide();
$("a.ui-slider-handle").show();
```

However, the user has to click at least twice on the slider before he/she can use the keyboards (i.e. `left` or `right` key) to move the handle.

Does someone know what is causing this behavior?

Comment: Please put your JS in the JavaScript box when using jsfiddle as that makes it easier to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the arrow keys to move the slider if the slider has focus.  Simple add:

```
$("a.ui-slider-handle").show().focus();
```

Note that if the slider loses focus, the arrow keys become disabled again.  You would have to bind `.keypress` or the like to `document` if you wanted them to respond regardless, but that's probably not the best idea.

Comment: thanks for the answer and that works. But is there any reason why the first click does not register the focus to the slider handle, while the second click does?

Comment: When you click the element cannot get focus since it is hidden.  Once shown you have to set focus.

Comment: I don't know for sure .. I think it's probably related to the browser (doesn't give focus to hidden elements).  When you click in the slider, jQuery may give focus to it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
$("a.ui-slider-handle").focus();
```

after

```
$("a.ui-slider-handle").show();
```

it maybe that you just need the element to get focus.